# JQuery animate onClick according to browser size

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, window-resize

Ive been trying to resolve the below code for weeks now but just cannot figure out what is wrong.  The below slides a menu in and out from the left hand side when the icon is selected, it also budges elements over to the right like a Facebook App.  However, I need it to be slightly different depending on the size of the browser (different elements on the page need moving).  It works fine on document ready but when I resize the browser, it tries to slide in and out multiple times and doesn't do the correct slide function according to the size.  Can anyone advise?

```
var menuInitialized = false;

function doMenu() {

$(".c_left, .top_right, .c_right, .c_myaccount, .header_image, .c_footer, .copyright, .accepts, .myaccount, .header_logo").removeAttr('style');

var $menu = $(".c_left");
var width = $(window).width();
var status = 'closed';

if (width < 550) {
    if (!menuInitialized) {
        $('.icon-menu-2').on('click', function(event) {
            alert('small'); //test which is being activated onclick
            if (status === 'closed') {
                $menu.animate({
                    width: 185,
                    marginLeft: 0,
                    display: 'toggle'
                }, 'fast');
                $(".top_right, .c_right, .c_myaccount, .c_footer, .copyright, .accepts").animate({
                    marginLeft: 185,
                    display: 'toggle'
                }, 'fast');
                $(".myaccount").animate({
                    marginRight: -185,
                    display: 'toggle'
                }, 'fast');
                return status = 'open';
            } else if (status === 'open') {
                $menu.animate({
                    width: 0,
                    marginLeft: -185,
                    display: 'toggle'
                }, 'fast');
                $(".top_right, .c_right, .c_myaccount,.c_footer, .copyright, .accepts").animate({
                    marginLeft: 0,
                    display: 'toggle'
                }, 'fast');
                $(".myaccount").animate({
                    marginRight: 0,
                    display: 'toggle'
                }, 'fast');
                return status = 'closed';
            }
        });
        menuInitialized = true;
    }
} else if ((width < 800) && (width > 550)) {
    if (menuInitialized) {
        $('.icon-menu-2').on('click', function(event) {
            alert('large'); //test which is being activated onclick
            if (status === 'closed') {
                $menu.animate({
                    width: 185,
                    marginLeft: 0,
                    display: 'toggle'
                }, 'fast');
                $(".top_right, .c_right, .c_myaccount, .header_image, .c_footer, .copyright, .accepts").animate({
                    marginLeft: 185,
                    display: 'toggle'
                }, 'fast');
                $(".myaccount, .header_logo").animate({
                    marginRight: -185,
                    display: 'toggle'
                }, 'fast');
                return status = 'open';
            } else if (status === 'open') {
                $menu.animate({
                    width: 0,
                    marginLeft: -185,
                    display: 'toggle'
                }, 'fast');
                $(".top_right, .c_right, .c_myaccount, .header_image,.c_footer, .copyright, .accepts").animate({
                    marginLeft: 0,
                    display: 'toggle'
                }, 'fast');
                $(".myaccount, .header_logo").animate({
                    marginRight: 0,
                    display: 'toggle'
                }, 'fast');
                return status = 'closed';
                }
            });
            menuInitialized = false;
        }
    }
}
$(document).ready(doMenu);
$(window).resize(doMenu);
```

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle?

Comment: Ive attempted to do a simplified version here: http://jsfiddle.net/cDppA/7/, however I cannot even get the click function to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to unbind the click function ie: `$('.icon-menu').unbind('click');`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe:

```
var timeoutResize;
$(window).resize(function(){ 
        clearTimeout(timeoutResize);
        timeoutResize = setTimeout(doMenu,50);

    });
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work.I have added alert ('small') and alert('large') to the code to try and see which  .icon-menu-2').on('click', function(event) is being executed on browser resize and it alerts ('small') on document ready and still alerts small even when resized above 550px when it should alert 'large'.

Answer (score 0):

Roasted's solution should work. In most browser's the resize event fires continuously as the window is resized. Depending on what you are doing in the handler you may need to introduce a delay to wait for the resizing to finish before executing the handler code.